# Why do I get error when I try to alert the length of the passed array to the function?

Tags: javascript

Why do I get error when I try to alert the length of the passed array to the function:
Here is code:

```
<div>
    <button onclick = "CreatTable()">click me!</button>
</div>

<script type ="text/javascript">
        var data = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'];

        function CreatTable(data) {
        alert(data.length);
}
</script>
```

In this row:

alert(data.length);

I get this error:

**TypeError: data is undefined**

Why I get this error? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: I press the button see  update

Comment: you are not passing any parameter to createTable()

Comment: You call the function without arguments: `CreatTable()`. So `data` become `undefined`

Comment: remove `data` param from `CreatTable` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rebinding name `data` to a function argument. And calling it without any arguments. Sure `data` is undefined.

```
function CreatTable() { //use scoped variable data.
        alert(data.length);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rebinding name" ?

Comment: @Michael - I think you have a misunderstanding of the fundamentals of functions, variables and scopes. Ask yourself what you expect `.length` to be of: the argument to the function, or the array you defined outside of it?

Comment: Thanks Yury,now I undertsnd the problem.

Comment: Spec (ECMA-2.62) defines a series of steps javascript engine should perform to resolve variable names. Consider the following case `var x = 1; function y(x){ var x = 2; console.log(x);}; y(3);` What is name `x` binded to? Outer variable, function argument, or inner variable? More details here http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf section 10.5 Declaration Binding Instantiation page 59

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <button onclick = "CreatTable()">click me!</button>
</div>

<script type ="text/javascript">
        var data = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'];

        function CreatTable() {
            alert(data.length);
        }
</script>
```

Either pass `data` as an argument to `CreatTable`, or remove it and it'll refer to the `data` array you've defined.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function without an argument
`CreatTable()`

whereas your function definition takes `data` as argument.

Because `data` is a global variable, just remove it from the function definition:

write `function CreatTable() {`

instead of

`function CreatTable(data) {`